# Deploying ASP.net Core 2.0 to windows server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-8

I have deployed asp.net core 2.0 application to windows server 2012 where MsSQL 2017 is installed. Am getting the below error when I request a database related method.

appsettings.json contents are :

```
 {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=MGSERVER2012\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestingCoreIdentity;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

The error details :
[image]

Comment: Are you registering service configuration for `ConnectionString` in startup.cs?
And How are you instantiating database connection.

Comment: Yes am doing so, The application works pretty fine on local machine from visual studio 2017. Here is my code in configureServices :   services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So What I did in my app (CORE 1.0 , should be similar in 2.0)

Registered in configuration -

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            #region connection
            services.AddDbContext<TWCStoreContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Data:DefaultConnection")));
            #endregion
            services.Configure<ConfigData>(Configuration.GetSection("Data"));
         }
```

In the context file -

```
public partial class TWCStoreContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly IOptions<ConfigData> _ConfigData;

        public TWCStoreContext(DbContextOptions<TWCStoreContext> options, IOptions<ConfigData> ConfigData)
       : base(options)
        {
            _ConfigData = ConfigData;
        }

  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_ConfigData.Value.DefaultConnection);
        }

    }
```

Config -

```
public class ConfigData
    {
        public string DefaultConnection{ get; set; }
    }
```

Make sure you are not missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Need to specify the connection string name as below in Startup.cs ConfigureServices method. Replace your application DBContext to *"YourDBContext"*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(op => p.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my Question :
I have created new user in management studio with full persmission and used this connection string in appsettings.json

```
 "DefaultConnection": "Server=MGSERVER2012\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=AspCoreUser;Password=Password@123"
```

I have also granted windows permission for Users group for appsettings.json.